# Kendo UI Web Grid - Select All Performance Issue

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui

Have anyone had performance issue when creating a select all / deselect all on the toolbar and  the update is very slow.  It took around 10 seconds to iterate through 300 records in the grid using the datasource set/get methods.

The code I used is as follows:

```
    var data = dataSource.view();
    for (var idx = 0, length = data.length; idx < length; idx++) {
        if (!data[idx].IsActive) data[idx].set("IsActive", true);
    }
```

Anyone encountered this issue?  Is there a way to improve the performance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Three questions:

1. if you are going to set `IsActive` to `true`, don't spend time checking if it is already `true`;
2. Instead of `set`ting it assign the value directly, `set` is a pretty expensive operation and then do a refresh to update the UI.
3. Your computer is much faster than mine, in my case 300 values took much longer ;-)

Try doing:

```
var data = dataSource.view();
for (var idx = 0, length = data.length; idx < length; idx++) {
    data[idx].Active = true;
}
grid.refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calculating length of data everytime ,store length in local variable
like this

```
  var data = dataSource.view();
  var dataLength=data.length;
  for (var idx = 0, length = dataLength; idx < length; idx++) {
         data[idx].Active = true;
  }
  grid.refresh();
```

Comment: And why is your answer nearly an exact copy of the snippet that @OnaBai provided in http://stackoverflow.com/a/15863158/2759848 ?